# Problems with android pre- defined themes

Tags: android, android-theme

Is there any resource to know about android pre-defined themes?

**This is not about creating custom themes**. I have gone through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

I am confused with themes like Theme.AppCompat.Light,android:Theme.Material etc.

I want to know when to use what, and how they appear on the screen.
(The problem is I am using these themes but don't know how it affect the UI)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The material theme is only available in Android 5.0 (API level
>   21) and above. The v7 Support Libraries provide themes with material
>   design styles for some widgets and support for customizing the color
>   palette. For more information, see Maintaining Compatibility.

stick to Theme.AppCompat if your app supports earlier versions of android. you can also provide alternative layouts for api 21 and above